# Integrate over 2d polygon quadpy

Tags: python, integration, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate a function on a 2d polygon described by its vertices as follow

```python
import numpy as np
import quadpy


def f(x):
    return x[0]


poly = np.array([[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [0, 1], [1,1]])

scheme = quadpy.t2.get_good_scheme(10)
val = scheme.integrate(f, poly)
```

But I get

> QuadpyError: Wrong domain shape.

I really appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

`quad.t2` is for triangles, three points are expected. Your polygon is a square, you have to use [`quad.c2`](https://github.com/sigma-py/quadpy#quadrilateral-c2).

```py
import quadpy

scheme = quadpy.c2.get_good_scheme(7)
val = scheme.integrate(
    lambda x : x[0],
    [ [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0]], [[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]] ]
)
val
```

This gives `0.5`, which is easy to get mathematically.

See the link for the way to specify the quadrilateral.